# How to launch application after silent installation in advanced installer

Tags: build, advanced-installer

First, I import resources.

Then I tick "Limit to basic user interface" in Install Parameters -> Installation Options.

Then I go to Custom Actions and create "Launch File" after "Finish Execution", 
File to launch = "APPDIR\Test.exe", conditions = "NOT Installed", others default, as written here http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-launch-application.html

That's all I do

But while installing it messages "There is a problem... A program run as part of the setup did not finish... ";

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the path you enter in the "File to launch" field is not correct. To make sure that the correct path to the file is used you can simple right-click into that field, select "File...", then choose the file that you want to launch from the dialog that appears (the path will be formatted like this: [#Test.exe]).

In order to use a property you can write it like this: [APPDIR]Test.exe.

If the problem persists create and attach here a verbose log of the installation.

Comment: Ok, I have changed the field to "[#Test.exe]", and the installer launches my program, closes itself and my program continues. As my program does not exit, i unticked "wait for custom action before proceeding" and "wait for return code at the end of the sequence". Installer closes, but the process of installer in task manager doesn't close/ Is it still waiting?